# C# Bindingsource filtering

Tags: c#, filter, datagridview, bindingsource

I've got a question about filtering of a bindingsource in C# (Visual Studio).

I've got a large amount of rows with data which I'd like to filter on two columns, namely the city and the number of smokers. 
(This is dummydata to make it clearer).

```
 +-----------+-----------+
|   City    | Smoker Qty |
+-----------+------------+
| Amsterdam |    4448    |
| Paris     |    1477    |
| Stockholm |      23    |
| Moskou    |    5484    |
| New York  |       0    | 
| Istanbul  |    1665    |
| Dublin    |       0    |
| Tokyo     |     938    |
| Singapore |     756    |
| London    |    7194    |
+-----------+------------+
```

So, I've got a column called 'City' and a column called 'Smoker Qty'.

Now, let's say I'd like to know how many smokers each city within the range

```
Stockholm
London
Dublin
```

have. 
But, as Dublin has no smokers I don't want the city listed/visible.

So, in my result, it would only show (what i wish):

```
+-----------+------------+
|   City    | Smoker Qty |
+-----------+------------+
| Stockholm |      23    |
| London    |    7194    |
+-----------+------------+
```

I've already tried to do it like this, but yet without any succes. 
I'm very curious to your ideas on how to get to this.

```
    string Filter01 = "City = 'Amsterdam'";
    string Filter02 = "City = 'London'";
    string Filter03 = "City = 'Dublin'";
    string Filter04 = "'Smoker Qty' <> '0'";

    //string TotalFilter = Filter01 + Filter02 + Filter03;

    bindingSource1.Filter = "(" + Filter01 + " OR " + Filter02 + " OR " + Filter03 + ") AND " + Filter04;
```

Thanks in advance! 
F.

Comment: Would you also post your datagrid code as well.  Please read about posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: I don't think this will work `'Smoker Qty' <> '0'`. Did you try `[Smoker Qty] <> 0` (assumming that field is an int).

Comment: Dear Rick S, the reason I've not included the entire code is because of some sensitive/confidential data it contains (should have mentioned that though, correct). 
For now, Rene's solution has worked for me, that's great! 
Thanks for your help thusfar!